# "Partially" distributive conditional types

Tags: typescript

I want to have a conditional type, that is a "partially" [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). More specifically I want to treat undefined separately regarding the distributive behavior. Is this possible?

```
type ToArray<Type> = [Type] extends [any] ? Type[] : never
type ToArrayOrUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? undefined : ToArray<T>
type Test1 = ToArray<string | number> //=> (string | number)[] (OK)
type Test2 = ToArray<string | number | undefined> // => (string | number | undefined)[] (OK)
type Test3 = ToArrayOrUndefined<string | number | undefined> // number[] | string[] | undefined, but should be (string | number)[] | undefined
type Test4 = ToArrayOrUndefined<string | number> // number[] | string[], but should be (string | number)[]
```

Comment: Instead of thinking of this as a "partially distributive" type, it would make more sense to phrase this in terms of a pair of distributive types that give you behavior you want for `undefined` and non-`undefined` separately (e.g., `Extract` and `Exclude`).  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wejrKN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the trick, where the essential difference with your code is that `undefined` is a sub-type of a union containing `undefined`, not the other way round:

```
type ToArray<T> = [T] extends [any] ? T[] : never;
type ToArrayOrUndefined<T> = [undefined] extends [T]
  ? ToArray<Exclude<T, undefined>> | undefined
  : ToArray<T>;

type Test1 = ToArray<string | number>
// => (string | number)[]
type Test2 = ToArray<string | number | undefined>
// => (string | number | undefined)[]
type Test3 = ToArrayOrUndefined<string | number | undefined>
// => (string | number)[] | undefined
type Test4 = ToArrayOrUndefined<string | number>
// => (string | number)[]
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gQQE5IIYgDwwHxQLxQDaMAulBAB7AQB2AJgM5Go0hkD8shZAXFDRABuEJAG4AUKEixEKdAHkkAVXoQAZgEsBdLLgKEArqs3aylavSbES4qFE7xkaTAFEKAYwA2BuhCwAaKCNfEwg6bFwAHyDjLTDbKD5HOUwcCUlwaBgIBmAARnwZJ3QMXKQtAHMoaJoDAFsAIxFscQB6VvxcAAoyyur%20eqakAEpuDOls3IAmQuTnUuBymiqawZF%204PU48LaOvG7e5f7axvXozdC6UZspLJzgAGZZ2WdFFRDthaWVgdOkDdi2ha7U6UB6iz6qz%201wBH204zuuQALM9iiA3oCwl9Ib8hsC9gcIUcoUNruIgA)

(Though, I can hardly see the point of such an approach: how is that better than directly a `type Test3 = ToArray<string | number> | undefined`?  Moreover, consider a `type Test5 = ToArray<string | number | undefined> | undefined`, and there is no way to rewrite that as a `ToArrayOrUndefined`, so that `ToArrayOrUndefined` is not even very general.)

Comment: Thanks! (I agree that in this particular use case it did not make a lot of sense, but it was basically a minimal representative example of what I wanted to achieve in another more elaborate use case where it indeed makes some sense :))